# is it possible to connect from electron to WSL mariadb installed?

Tags: electron, mariadb, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'd like to create a simple application using [electron](https://electronjs.org/) in windows 10 and I would like to use mariadb as a database. Now I have mariadb installed in WSL, is it possible to connect from electron to WSL mariadb installed?

Comment: That's what I'm asking if its possible, since they are both on same platform, WSL is a subsystem for windows as i understand, I am not using typical ubuntu/unix, I am on windows

Answer (score 0):

I tried it,

once `sudo service mysql start` and mysql start, you can now connect to the database.